# how to create database pool in websphere to connect to db2

Tags: db2, websphere, websphere-ce

I am participating in ibm tgmc 2011. For that project I need to work on ibm products websphere(Community Edition),db2-express c edition,eclipse.

I want to know how to create database pool in websphere. I used the administrative console and in first step of giving name  in second step i selected db2 9.5 version and given the username and password,i couldn't  understand its not going forward no responses no error report nothing.

my installation details:

- websphere community edition 3.0
- db2 express-c edition v9.7

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: i left it over there later i used apache tomcat + db2